# Conditional replacement across data frames using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, conditional-statements

I am rather new to Python and have a question about conditional replacement across data frames.

I have two data frames, A and B and I would like to update the dates in A with the dates in B whenever there are matching id (nid).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nid1 = (1, 3, 4, 8)
date1 = ("2010-02-01", "2008-06-05", "2011-03-15", "2009-02-17") 
info1 = ("b", "m", "d", "m")

nid2 = (1, 3)
date2 = ("2010-08-01", "2008-01-01") 
    
dfa = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(nid1, date1, info1)),  columns =['nid', 'date', 'info']) 
dfb = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(nid2, date2)),  columns =['nid', 'date'])
```

I would like to update the date variable in dfa to the data variable in dfb whenever there are matching id's.

I have without luck tried converting A to a dictionary to replace

```
dict_b = dfb.set_index('nid').to_dict()['date']
dfa["date"].replace(dict_b, inplace=True)
```

Or using np.where

```
np.where(dfa["nid"].isin(dfb["nid"]), dfb["date"], dfa["date"])
```

Can anyone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
print (dfb.set_index("nid").combine_first(dfa.set_index("nid")))

           date info
nid                 
1    2010-08-01    b
3    2008-01-01    m
4    2011-03-15    d
8    2009-02-17    m
```